# Convert fixed frequency bandwidth samples to time domain

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, frequency-domain, time-domain

I'm trying to convert signal (bandwidth **1400 MHz**, start freq **9300 MHz**, stop freq **10700 MHz**, step **3.5 MHz**) from frequency domain to time domain. Signal data in frequency domain, as well as signal data in time domain, I got from network analyzer. So after processing data from freq to time I'm able to compare results. *The problem is, that my calculation result differs from network analyzer data.* You can see it on the picture below. Blue line - data from network analyzer, green line - my calculation result. Picture (a) is a signal in frequency domain, picture (b) - signal in time domain. In time domain step is **5e-10 seconds**. Does anyone has any suggestions? Maybe Network analyzer freq data simply has not enough resolution to convert to time domain correctly as Network analyzer do? Thank you.

[image: (a) original signal in frequency domain]

[image: (b) signal in time domain, calculated by me and from network analyzer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspect, it was an issue with insufficient number of points in freq domain data. I convert time domain data from the green trace to freq domain and got exactly the same values in freq domain as on the first picture with original freq data from network analyzer.